# Iterate over every element of of a dict with its key

Tags: python

Suppose you have a dict like this

```
dict_h = {'seven': [8, 9, 10]}
```

And I want to iterate over it like this

```
for key, values in dict_h.items():
    for value in values:
        print('key value', key, value)
```

Is there any way to do that in one line? I looked through itertools to see if there was something but came up with nothing.

Ideally something like

```
for key, value in iter_keyvalue(dict_h):
    print('key value', key, value)
```

In both cases, I'd want the output to be

```
"key value seven 8"
"key value seven 9"
"key value seven 10"
```

Comment: You can, but remember that in most cases, you should consider readability over reducing some lines,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generator expression which does this:

```
((key, value) for key, values in dict_h.items() for value in values)
```

If you use this generator, you have one line:

```
for key, value in ((key, value) for key, values in dict_h.items() for value in values):
    print('key value', key, value)
```

If you need this several times, you can of course build a function out of it:

```
def iter_keyvalue(d):
    return ((key, value) for key, values in d.iteritems() for value in values)
```

and then use it as you suggested.

Note that you can write the function as a generator function on its own:

```
def iter_keyvalue(d):
    for key, values in d.iteritems():
        for value in values:
            yield key, value
```

The first one creates the generator object from a generator expression, the second one is a "proper" generator function which exactly does the same.

Both versions are functionally equivalent. The only visible difference is the generator object's `__name__`s, which is `'<genexpr>'` in the first case and `'iter_keyvalue'` in the second case. This difference is also visible in the `repr` of the objects.

While the second one looks cleaner, the first one is closer to the OP's request to have only one line.

Comment: istead of `return` you should be having `yield` to keep it working as a generator.

Comment: And it is actually not working. Should be `yield ((key, value) for key, values in d.items() for value in values)`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Indeed it did not work, but not because of a missing `yield`, but because of missing parentheses in the generator expression. A generator expression is another valid approach to create a generator object. Nevertheless I now show two alternatives to create this function.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) combining the nested loops, e.g:

```
>>> dict_h = {'seven': [8, 9, 10]}
>>> print(*["key value {} {}".format(k, v) for k, values in dict_h.items() for v in values], sep="\n")
key value seven 8
key value seven 9
key value seven 10
```

That said, in code that will have to be maintained, you should really favour [readability](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) over brevity.

Answer (score 3):

```
dic_h = {'seven': [8, 9, 10]}
```

This works for your situation:

```
print('\n'.join(["Key Value {} {}".format(k, v) for k in dic_h for v in dic_h[k]]))

Key Value seven 8
Key Value seven 9
Key Value seven 10
```

This solution make use of a List Comprehension.

More info on List Comprehensions [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), and [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python%20list%20comprehension&atb=v19&ia=web).

Also, Google `str.join` if it's new to you.

Comment: Instead of a List Comprehension, it would have been enough to use a generator expression. Looks nearly the same, but has a possible difference on the running time and memory consumption.

Comment: @glglgl It probably would be faster.

Comment: @glglgl I actually timed both using the timeit module. There was virtually no difference, but if anything, the list comprehension version tended to be faster(we're talking by 0.01/0.02 s)... which I didn't expect. Perhaps that's an anomaly, but either way, they were virtually identical with this tiny amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

One line would be:

```
for key, value in ((key, value) for key, values in dict_h.items() for value in values): print('key, value', key, value)
```

Comment: That's kind of a fake "one line" though ;)

Comment: @mrCarnivore it is not working properly though.. Did you run it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Not the most understandable complaint since I did run it before I posted it. However, after rereading the question you are right and I misread the request and have modified my answer to reflect that.